# Is it possible to extend checkstyle architecture for other languages?

Tags: antlr, extend, checkstyle

I am looking for static code anaylyzer for some SQL scripts written.  I was interested in having a tool that can be extended with my own set of rules.

For static code analysis I see lot of tools for java like checkstyle, PMD etc. which can be extended with custom rules.

Based on some inputs in [Static code analysis for new language. Where to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869935/static-code-analysis-for-new-language-where-to-start) I decided to use ANTLR. With ANTLR it looks like I have to create lot of code to achieve what I am looking for. So took a look at tools that use ANTLR(Checkstyle is one of them)

I am trying to see if the code already created by Checkstyle can be extended to parse my new grammar file and use all the Check rules that it allows to add

Please let me know if there are other better tools to achieve the same

Comment: ANTLR provides parsing.  Static analysis requires lots more than parsing.  See my essay on Life Beyond Parsing http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html.